# Unity Convert Raycast Radius from 3D to 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a 2D videogame with top down view. In this game I am using a flashlight. The problem is the only tutorial I found is 3D and I struggle converting the code into 2D.

```
public class Lightning : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Light")]
    public float ViewRadius;
    public float ViewAngle;
    public Vector3 DirfromAngle(float angle)
    {
        return new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad),0, Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    }
}
```

This is the code in 3D, when converting it to 2D I have

```
public class Lightning : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Light")]
    public float ViewRadius;
    public float ViewAngle;
    public Vector2 DirfromAngle(float angle)
    {
        return new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad), Mathf.Cos(angle * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
    }
}
```

I am using Unity Editor to visualize my radius which is in 3D:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Lightning))]
public class FieldofViewEditor : Editor {
void OnSceneGUI()
{
    Lightning fow = (Lightning)target;
    Handles.color = Color.white;
    Handles.DrawWireArc(fow.transform.position, Vector3.up,Vector3.forward, 
    360, fow.ViewRadius);
}
}
```

and in 2D:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Lightning))]
public class FieldofViewEditor : Editor {
    void OnSceneGUI()
    {
        Lightning fow = (Lightning)target;
        Handles.color = Color.white;
        Handles.DrawWireArc(fow.transform.position, 
        Vector2.up,Vector2.left, 360, fow.ViewRadius);
    }
}
```

When I have it in my game I only have a line instead of a Radius, I am assuming that its due it being with the wrong coordinates or me messing up the sinus or cosinus.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking down on the x-y plane, you want the normal of the arc to face back towards the camera, right now your normal is going up in the y-axis, meaning your arc is being drawn in the x-z plane. If you switch your camera to 3d you can probably see the arc. To draw the arc in the x-y plane, you should instead do:

```
    Handles.DrawWireArc(fow.transform.position, 
    Vector3.back,Vector2.left, 360, fow.ViewRadius);
```